# Call a dbus method in C++

Tags: c++, linux, dbus

I want to call the method `Refresh` of the `org.freedesktop.UPower.Device` interface using dbus in my C++ code. But I couldn't figure it out myself. Can someone briefly explain using dbus in a C++ program?

Comment: https://github.com/makercrew/dbus-sample#operator-well-could-you-help-me-place-this-call

Comment: The one in there seems more like the C way of doing dbus connections.

Comment: After further digging I think I will use QtDBus